# React defaultProps return Object field as string when using PropTypes.shape()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-proptypes

I am having input field, where I am passing props as `field={...}` my input component looks like this

```js
<Input field={fieldPropsObject}/>
```

```
fieldPropsObject = { label: 'Full name' }
```

now inside `Input` Component I am having these PropTypes and DefaultProps

These are PropTypes shape for `field:{...}` object

```
PrimaryInput.propTypes = {
  field: shape({
    label: string.isRequired,
    type: string,
    hintText: string,
    required: bool,
    disabled: bool,
    helperText: string,
    hintLink: string,
    size: string,
    fieldSchema: string,
    isFormik: bool,
}),
};
```

These are default props

```
Input.defaultProps = {
  field: {
    type: 'text',
    hintText: '',
    required: false,
    error: false,
    disabled: true,
    helperText: '',
    hintLink: '',
    size: '',
    fieldWidth: '',
    fieldSchema: 'string',
    isFormik: false,
  },
};
```

Now when I am passing the only label to `Input` component it gives a stringified version of default props instead of Object

here is how my component looks like in whole (this is just mock copy)

```
export const PrimaryInput = ({ field }) => {

  console.log(field); // look screenshot below

  return (...);
};

PrimaryInput.propTypes = {
  field: shape({
    label: string.isRequired,
    type: string,
    hintText: string,
    required: bool,
    disabled: bool,
    helperText: string,
    hintLink: string,
    size: string,
    fieldSchema: string,
    isFormik: bool,
}),
};

PrimaryInput.defaultProps = {
  field: {
    type: 'text',
    hintText: '',
    required: false,
    error: false,
    disabled: true,
    helperText: '',
    hintLink: '',
    size: '',
    fieldWidth: '',
    fieldSchema: 'string',
    isFormik: false,
  },
};
```

here how my console looks
[image]

I have tried using `objectOf(shape({..}))`, same results`

is there anything wrong I am doing, I couldn't catch up?

Any suggestions/Help will be appreciated, Thanks

Comment: I can't repro your issue. https://codesandbox.io/s/react-defaultprops-return-object-field-as-string-when-using-proptypes-shape-obgqw?file=/src/App.js Can you update your question to include a more [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example?

Comment: Hey @DrewReese, thank you so much for taking out time and responding to my question, I have checked example code on code sandbox, but couldn't produce the issue, let me double-check my component,

Comment: Have you a status update on checking your component?

Comment: Sorry drew I couldn't update, I verified this issue I noticed that it's due to storybook I am using